# Twitter - Stream vs GET search

Tags: api, twitter, oauth, stream, get

What is the main differences between "annonymous" GET search and "authorized" stream search of tweets? What about limitations? Which method is more suitable for searching tweets with concrete entities (expanded_url)?

Also is there any reason why should I use OAuth authentification? I mean this script: http://dmacias.org/2010/12/31/playing-around-with-twitter-api-using-tweepy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an OAuth link to a user, you can see a user's private tweets as well as their public tweets. OAuth is also needed to post tweets. If all you're interested in doing is looking at people's public tweets, then OAuth is not needed.